# Flutter assets image not find

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I use Visual studio code and Andriod studio IDE and different AVD managers but when I run app with Image asset get an error No file or variants found for asset: assets/puffin.jpeg.

Simple example:
main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = 'Web Images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/puffin.jpeg",
            width: 280.0,
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: flutter_app_test
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/puffin.jpeg
```

run flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Have you loaded the app from cold ?

Comment: if I understand correctly what is cold start. (Cold Start is also known as splash screen,launch screen or cold start in android) No.

Comment: To add assets, you cannot do hot reloads.

Comment: Stop the app and start the app again. Hot reload won't work.

Comment: Running app wirhout hot reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix an error I delete folder **.dart_tool** and rerun app and error gone.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your .yaml file.(it worked for me)**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    -android/assests/directory/
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure that your assets folder is in the root of your project, at the same level of the lib folder, like this:

```
my_project
-android
-assets //your image goes here, puffin.jpeg
-ios
-lib
-pubspec.yaml
-etc...
```

If you have your assets folder inside of another folder the IDE will not load the content inside it. Also, sometimes vs code does not load the changes in the pubspec file if you does not save it first, so, make sure that you save your project before you run "flutter pub get" in the terminal of the IDE.

Comment: Same project structure.

Comment: Can you post the output of running "flutter pub get"?

Comment: I get a message in puspec.yaml.The asset assets/puffin.jpeg does not exist.
Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file.dart(asset_does_not_exist). But when I do pub get do not get errors.

Comment: Try this, check your indentation, the line "assets:" need to have two spaces (one tab) and the line "- assets/puffin.jpeg" need to have four (two tabs) . After you check that, do "flutter clean" and run the app.