# Flutter Tflite PlatformException error model cannot be found yet its correctly mentioned

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow-lite

I am having a hard time with tflite in flutter

well the problem is the app cannot load the model but I did mention the asset in pubspec.yaml file and also I did spell the model name and the label text correctly still I am getting the error

**Pubspeck.yaml**

```
assets:
  - asset/fruit.txt
  - asset/model.tflite
  - asset/model_unquant.tflite
  - asset/labels2.txt
```

**Loading model**

```
loadModel() async {
    String res = await Tflite.loadModel(
        labels: "asset/labels2.txt",
        model: "asset/model_unquant.tflite",
    );
    print(res);
  }
```

**Predicting**

```
predict(String path) async {
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
        path: path,
        threshold: 0.3,
        imageMean: 0.0,
        imageStd: 255.0,
        numResults: 292
    );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
      char = _recognitions[0]["labels"];
      item = _recognitions[0];
    });
  }
```

**Traceback**

```
*E/flutter (18543): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Failed to load model, flutter_assets/asset/model_unquant.tflite, java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/asset/model_unquant.tflite*
E/flutter (18543):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAssetFd(Native Method)
E/flutter (18543):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:899)
E/flutter (18543):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.loadModel(TflitePlugin.java:207)
E/flutter (18543):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:95)
E/flutter (18543):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (18543):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (18543):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter (18543):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (18543):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (18543):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
E/flutter (18543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
E/flutter (18543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (18543):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
E/flutter (18543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
E/flutter (18543): , null)
E/flutter (18543): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
E/flutter (18543): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)
E/flutter (18543): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18543): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter (18543): #3      Tflite.loadModel (package:tflite/tflite.dart:16:27)
E/flutter (18543): #4      ResPicState.loadModel (package:respic/main.dart:53:31)
E/flutter (18543): #5      ResPicState.initState (package:respic/main.dart:48:5)
E/flutter (18543): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
E/flutter (18543): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (18543): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (18543): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (18543): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (18543): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (18543): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (18543): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (18543): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (18543): #15     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter (18543): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (18543): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (18543): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (18543): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (18543): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (18543): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (18543): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (18543): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (18543): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (18543): #25     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (18543): #26     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
E/flutter (18543): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (18543): #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter (18543): #29     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
E/flutter (18543): #30     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (18543): #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (18543): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (18543): #33     SingleChildRenderObjec
D/ViewRootImpl@6337ccf[MainActivity](18543): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6337ccf[MainActivity](18543): ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

I don't know what causes this error I have also tried using different version of tflite and different types of models and cleaned as well but the problem still persists.
Thanks for reading,
regards,
Roshan

Comment: Do you have `aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }` in your build.gradle?

Comment: Thanks for asking and yes I do in app level build.gradle under android

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306627/flutter-assets-image-not-find .I think it has nothing to do with TFlite

Answer (score 0):

remove asset in pubspec.yaml
It should be:
assets:

- fruit.txt
- model.tflite
- model_unquant.tflite
- labels2.txt